# Происхождение выражения «будем здоровы»

Tags: этимология, глаголы, наклонение, старославянский

В старославянском языке формы императива образовывались также и в 1 и 2 лицах множественного числа. Так, от глагола *бꙐти*:

> 1Pl — *бѫдѣмъ*
>   2Pl — *бѫдѣте*

Может ли этикетная формула *будем здоровы* (например, при произнесении тоста) быть связана с этим фактом? Иными словами, может ли глагол *будем* оказаться древней формой императива?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, это именно так и есть, ведь  повелительное наклонение — ирреальная форма будущего времени.

В старославянском и древнерусском языке формы повелительного наклонения выступали во 2-ом лице ед. ч. и **в 1-ом** и 2-ом лице **множественного** и двойственного числа.

В истории русского языка спряжение повелительного наклонения фактически разрушилось. Формы двойственного числа исчезли в результате общего процесса изменения категории числа. Формы первого лица множественного числа, видимо, утратились вследствие **слабой выразительности**: во многих случаях они оказывались омонимичны настоящему времени либо изначально, либо после утраты ятя, ср.: молилъ, нес^лхъ —> молим, несем. Однако соответствующее грамматическое значение (побуждение собеседника к совместному действию) в современном русском языке выражается при необходимости **исконными формами настоящего времени** (**современное будущее и реже настоящее**): пойдем! берем!

Форма 1-го лица мн. ч. повелительного наклонения была утрачена в истории языка, но вместе с тем начиная с XII – XIII вв. для выражения побуждения к совместному действию появляются образования, внешне сходные с формой 1-ого лица мн. ч. исконного  настоящего времени. Это была не просто замена одной формы другой формой, а выработка нового средства выражения к совместному действию. Данная форма имела значение и интонацию утраченной древнерусской формы повелительного наклонения.

Источники: https://studme.org/209713/literatura/istoriya_irrealnyh_nakloneniy

http://window.edu.ru/catalog/pdf2txt/112/22112/5339?p_page=8

https://www.liveinternet.ru/users/oprichnik46/post393451853